# Would a script being called by 150 other scripts slow it down?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, libraries

I have this one script that is used for code for a Slack bot. It was running fast before until I had to use it as library to be called by other scripts, now even a simple sending message takes more than 1 minute to do before it was just 8 seconds. The reason I am using it as a library because other scripts need to access the spreadsheet data in it, every row and column. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe make a copy of the script so that it's different from the one used as a library?